# Gallery height scale

Tags: css, image, bootstrap-4, gallery

I'm trying to fit image gallery with twitter bootstrap but I have some troubles to fit height exactly the same height.

I want to achieve 30px padding between all gaps (between small images and large image).

This is my code:

```
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="gallery__wrapper">
        <div class="gallery__container ">
          <div class="gallery__item gallery__item--small">
            <div class="gallery__item--media"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/810x461/e0e0e0/000000.jpg" alt=""></div>
          </div>
          <div class="gallery__item gallery__item--small">
            <div class="gallery__item--media"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/810x461/e0e0e0/000000.jpg" alt=""></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery__container">
          <div class="gallery__item gallery__item--large">
            <div class="gallery__item--media"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/810x964/e0e0e0/000000.jpg" alt=""></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QoeXYN

On xl screen it is OK, two columns have the same height, but for lg, md screen the large image is shorter. How can I achieve the same height and keep the same gap between images?